# optimization of multiple variable function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, data-science

I am trying to maximize revenue using costs for several products.

Here is my code:

In this piece of code, I calculate revenue for each product and then sum it.

```
   list = [65,78,90] #list of products
    def calcRev(x,list):
        sum = 0
        x = pd.DataFrame(x)
        for i in list:
                        count = 0
                        df_temp = df[df.app_id == i].reset_index()
                        df_temp['cost'] = x[count]
                        df_temp['inst'] = df_temp['cost']/df_temp['cpi']
                        df_temp['rev'] = (df_temp['LTV_accum']* df_temp['inst'])-df_temp['cost']
                        count = count+1
                        sum = sum+df_temp.rev.sum()
        return sum
```

objective function:

```
def obj(x,list):
    return -calcRev(x,list)
```

constraints:

```
    def constrglobal(x,list):
        return  10000-calcRev(x,list)
cons = ({'type':'ineq','fun':constrglobal,'args':(list,)})
```

then I initialize costs as initial guess `x`. Since I have two products as input `x` has two dims.
`x = np.full((15,), 0)`

then I apply minimize function:

```
sol = minimize(obj,x,args=(list,),method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,options={'disp':True})
```

But as solution I have data distributed only for first product:

```
sol.x
array([1467.64152006, 1442.41330009, 1417.18518617, 1391.95714139,
       1366.1311581 ,    0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,
          0.        ,    0.        ])
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong and how I can have `sol.x` distributed among all products?

Comment: Try not to use ```list``` as name variable, it can cause the problems with ```list()``` method.

Comment: You negate your revenue twice.  Are you trying to minimize revenue?

Comment: No, in this case I maximize revenue

Comment: Can you please write your output for list of 3 products?

Comment: here you are 

array([2418.81946988, 2380.1115163 , 2341.40366268, 2302.69578239,
       2263.11469374,    0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,
          0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,
          0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ])

Comment: I think the problem is that you are giving not ```(n,)``` shape ndarray ```x0 : ndarray, shape (n,)```. So try to reformat your ```(5,2 )``` array to ```(10,)``` array and then inside the function reformat it back to the ```(5,2)``` array.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to make x an 1d array, and still  faced the same problem

Comment: Can you please update your code, such that I can see the new version.

Comment: Done, updated the code

Comment: By " then inside the function reformat it back to the (5,2) array" I mean adding 
```x = x.reshape((5,len(list)))``` to the start of the ```calcRev``` function.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much, I resolved the issue when added  revenue sum for each product , like that:  return df_temp65.rev.sum()+df_temp78.rev.sum() in calcRev function